# How to make the margin of an element unchangeable by the size of adjacent elements?

Tags: html, css

Like when adding a text and a picture floating to the left.

Normally, when the text changes its digits, the picture will move its position to the left or right depending on the amount of digits.
Here is an example of what I mean:

```
<div>
    <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/blue-wavy-forms-on-a-transparent-background_1035-6744.jpg">
    <p>123</p>
    <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/blue-wavy-forms-on-a-transparent-background_1035-6744.jpg">
    <p>123</p>

</div>

<style>
    img{
        display:inline-block;
        height:30px;
    }
    p{
        display:inline;
    }
</style>
```

My question is: How to make the images' position static so that no matter the digits of the text beside it?

Comment: Do you want to consider using floats ?

Comment: Doesn't matter, but even when using "float: left", when the text's digits changes, the position of the picture on the right of it change, which is exactly what i don't want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give your text a width:

```
p{
     display:inline-block;
     width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Changed your markup a bit and added some CSS. Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

`html`

```
<div>
    <div class="image-container">
        <img class="left-floated-image" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/blue-wavy-forms-on-a-transparent-background_1035-6744.jpg">
        <p>1232323232323323</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
        <img class="left-floated-image" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/blue-wavy-forms-on-a-transparent-background_1035-6744.jpg">
        <p>1232323232323323</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

`css`

```
.image-container {
    display: inline-block;
}

img.left-floated-image {
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
}

p {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is wrap each of the image-paragraph pairs in their own `div` and float those divs next to each other. Give those divs a specific width.

Then, you can float the images to the left, and that will make the paragraphs wrap around them when they hit the boundary of their parent div, like so:

```css
div {
  float: left;
  width: 65px;
}
img {
  float: left;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/blue-wavy-forms-on-a-transparent-background_1035-6744.jpg">
  <p>123 456 789 101112</p>
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/blue-wavy-forms-on-a-transparent-background_1035-6744.jpg">
  <p>123</p>
</div>
```

Note that if you float the image *and* paragraphs left, the paragraphs will only float next to the images if their container div is wide enough to fit them both (which in this example below it is not, thus the first paragraph wraps below the first image).

```css
div {
  float: left;
  width: 65px;
}
img {
  float: left;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
p {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/blue-wavy-forms-on-a-transparent-background_1035-6744.jpg">
  <p>123 456 789 101112</p>
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/blue-wavy-forms-on-a-transparent-background_1035-6744.jpg">
  <p>123</p>
</div>
```